# excel sum vlookup by delimiter

Tags: for-loop, google-sheets, sum, vlookup

I'm trying to make a sum in Google Spreadsheet based on array of productnames. The productnames (single products and combined products) are listed horizontally and dynamically by a query like this. The combined product-headers are delimited with pipes "|".

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Product_Range;"select A where "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(B1;Customer_Range;0);4);1;"")&" > 0"))
```

I could make a static formula for the delimited productheaders (e.g. "Product 1|Add-on 1|Add-on 3") with summing up the relevant columns, but the sequence of headers/productnames could change on edit. For example the columnheader "Addon-on 1" could be "Product 2" in the future. So I want to make it all dynamically.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gJAZHLst707rnfcDTDYWwoLneSwhGgezYaCYpLKOtLI/edit?usp=sharing

The prices for single products are being fetched by this formula:

```
=SUM(
(VLOOKUP($A2 ;Products_Range ;MATCH( C$4; Products_Price_Range  ;0);FALSE)) * 
(VLOOKUP(C$4; Factor_Range; MATCH( Customer_Name;Customers_Range  ;0);FALSE)) )
```

I need some kind of loop to use this formula for each productitem nested in a delimited productheader.

I've made a custom function in Google Script to do this but the performance was really slow because of the quantity of rows and connected sheets.

So I was hoping to make this work fast with a native formula.

Could you please advice how to use my sum-formula for each item (single product columns and/or array-based product columns) ?

I hope this possible?

Comment: Please use the Gsheet-link above.

Comment: For example B3. If the formula works in this cell. Then we can expand it to B3:F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clear B3:B1950**

B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B2;Factor!A:E;MATCH(A1;Factor!1:1;0);0)*MMULT(VLOOKUP(A3:A1949;Prices!A:E;(MATCH(SPLIT(B2;"|");Prices!1:1;0));0);(ROW(A1:index(A:A;counta(SPLIT(B2;"|"))))^0)))
```

*From the inside to the outside: Starting from the split inside mmult/match*

- Split B2 by delimiter and create matched indexes
- Feed all  that different indexes to vlookup,which looks up all formats
- Matrix multiply them with a vertical 1s array (size = count of combined different products in the combined entity) *//This is not needed, If you're looking for just 1 result instead of a array.*
- Find Factor to multiply through Vlookup/Match
- Multiply factor with all the mmult output array to give final result.

EDIT:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(VLOOKUP(A3:A1949;Prices!A:E;(MATCH(SPLIT(B2;"|");Prices!1:1;0));0);transpose(VLOOKUP(Split(B2;"|");Factor!A:C;MATCH(A1;Factor!1:1;0);0))))
```

Comment: Great formula! Thank you very much. For Customer 2 (see A1) the sum is correct, because the multiply-factor is 1 (see sheet Factor). Could you please take a look at B3 for Customer 1. B3 should give € 17,97 as response.

Comment: My mistake, I don't want to use 1 factor for a combined product, but the relevant factors for each productname mentioned in the array. I've edited the sheet 'Factor'.

Comment: I'm trying. I think I should stay in MMULT loop for multiplying each product-amount with the relevant factor.

For single productnames this formula shows the relevant factor.
=VLOOKUP("Product 1";Factor!A:C;MATCH(A1;Factor!A1:C1);FALSE)

Could you please advice one more time?